# Transfer IOS app from one Enterprise Account to Another Enterprise Account

Tags: ios, iphone, enterprise

We have an enterprise app , which we need to migrate to another enterprise account . We dont want our users to do a re-install after the migration , but it looks like when we create the same bundle id in our new enterprise app and update on top of the existing app , the update fails saying the entitlements mismatch , probably because the team -id differs in the new account.

Is there any way we can migrate an app from one enterprise account to other without making our users re-install.

Please note that im talking about the migration of the app from one enterprise account to other , not about the developer account migration.